# Is there a way to detect if a content deployment is ready?

Tags: export, import, content-deployment

I need to detect if a content deployment between two different sharepoint 2010 farms is finished. Is there a way to achieve this programmatically? I've been looking around for some days now but without success.

Are there any Event-Handlers or CustomActions I can use? At the moment I'm building my own deployment job using `SPImport`and `SPExport`but that seems many overhead for me. All I need to do is to execute a simple function when the content deployment is finished.

Thank you very much!
LMW

P.S.
I'm using Sharepoint2010 and VS2010/C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the *ContentDeploymentJobStatus* until it returns "Success". You can use code like below.

```
ContentDeploymentJobCollection cdJobCollection = ContentDeploymentJob.GetAllJobs();

                                   foreach (ContentDeploymentJob job in definitionCollection)
                                   {
                                       if (job.Name.StartsWith(strYourJobName.ToLower()) && job.LastStatus==ContentDeploymentJobStatus.Success)
                                       return true;
                                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to send the success / error email to an email enabled SharePoint list. In that list you'll have a receiver on item added that can execute some code on the site collection / web app / farm ... depending on the elevation / work to be executed.

You could also do a little bit of screenscrapping on the central administration dashboards but that it's even clumsier than the first suggested solution.

Kindly